# QGIS 3.26 - Field missing in field calculator

Tags: qgis

[Screenshot to clarify the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bshrA.png)

I'm trying to use the substr function in the field "Municipio" to create a new one called "Código" but even tough you can see the field Municipio in the attributes table, the field calculator doesn't find it.

In the screenshot you can't see the reason of the error but it is: 'Field "Municipio" not found'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Short story - you have to put the field names in quotes.

---

It is better to select the field names for formulas from the list (expand e.g. `Campos y valores`) to the right by double mouse click and thus avoid typing errors.

[image]